# A question asking for a list of use-cases for a language feature... too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

[This C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45480824/2069064) begins by listing a couple use-cases for the new C++17 language feature named structured bindings, before asking:

> Can you provide some other, possibly less obvious use cases for structured bindings? How else can they improve readability or even performance of C++ code?

This strikes me as the epitome of "Too broad" and I helped close it as such. However, I notice it has since been voted to be reopened. There aren't any new comments on the question arguing that it be reopened, it just was voted to be reopened. I can't VTC it again, but does this question actually merit remaining open?

Comment: My guess is it depends on the feature. I am not sure how to explain the difference between the linked question and "How do I use inheritance in Java", but the difference is there. This is more of a language-lawer question...

Comment: IMHO, the "broadness" comes from the use of the slippery word "use cases" and not (necessarily) the question as a whole.  Will make a suggestion on the post itself...

Comment: @Arkadiy This is not at all a language-lawyer question.

Comment: @gnat Odd that you suggest that this question is a duplicate of one saying that the question should be closed as too broad, and yet you voted to reopen it.

Comment: @Servy looking back I think I probably made a mistake voting reopen (did that primarily because I liked top answer and that made me miss the issues in the question)